# Using Sipeed 6+1 microphone array be used with Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: audio, pi-zero-w

Can I actually use [Sipeed 6+1 microphone array](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Maix_R6+1_Microphone_Array) with Raspberry Pi Zero W? The microphone array has a 10P 0.5mm FPC, but can it be made to work with the Pi. If not can the GPIO connectors be used to get the audio signals?

Datasheet: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/5/58/Sipeed_R6%2B1_Microphone_Array_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf

Schematic: https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/e/e7/Sipeed-R6%2B1_MicArray_11.16%28Schematic%29_%281%29.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No its a 4 channel i2s dumb board whilst the pi has a single i2s channel for a single l/r pair.

Also there is a myth that an array on its own is somehow good but without the DSP simple summing creates some pretty bad high pass filters.

https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Microphone-Array-Beamforming.pdf

adafruit have a tutorial on how you can connect and set up a driver for a single l/r i2s mic pair
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-test

Often if voice a soundcard with a unidirectional mic can have much advantage over omnidirectional as 2x Omnidirectional is of little use maybe the sum of the gain might be a little more than the sum of the SNR that they produce.